# Ruby net/ssh hangs with specific host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, net-ssh

I have an issue where if I'm trying to create a ssh connection to a specific host, the connection hangs without timing out. I have tried connecting to this host from the same machine from outside the rails console and it works so I'm assuming this shouldn't be anything related to routing/firewall. I can also confirm I have several other hosts with the exact same OS configuration in different places and they work.

This is the log when running `Net::SSH.start` in debug mode:

```
ssh = Net::SSH.start("1.2.3.4", "user", password: "password", verbose: :debug)
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] establishing connection to 1.2.3.4:22
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] connection established
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [INFO] negotiating protocol version
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3'
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_2.6.8 i686-linux'
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] read 704 bytes
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] received packet nr 0 type 20 len 700
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [INFO] got KEXINIT from server
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [INFO] sending KEXINIT
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1620
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] sent 1624 bytes
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [INFO] negotiating algorithms
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] exchanging keys
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
2014-02-27 13:17:43 +0100 [DEBUG] sent 24 bytes
```

At this point the ssh connection just hangs and could stay like this for 15-30 minutes.
Unfortunately I have no error message or anything so I'm really clueless about what the problem might be.

Some specs:

```
ruby-2.0.0-p0
rails (3.2.13)
net-ssh-2.8.0
```

The IP address in the log is not a real IP on purpose.

Any suggestion about what the problem could be? Or maybe some other log or place I could check out? I found a similar problem outside SO but it didn't get a solution so I'm trying to ask here...

Comment: and no block is evaliated?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I'm not using a block. Just trying to get a ssh object: `ssh = Net::SSH.start("1.2.3.4", "user", password: "password", verbose: :debug)`

Comment: so the process haven't reach that line?

Comment: That's the line that's attempting to open the connection. The connection is clearly halted because there should be more data exchange between client and server.

Comment: `[DEBUG] negotiated:` isn't this line says about data exchange?

Comment: Did you find solution to this? I'm having similar problem, but it stops at net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:103 and says connection closed by remote host (Net::SSH::Disconnect)

Comment: @JoelHandwell Unfortunately no. But if you find something please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I solved by reducing [maximum transmission unit](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/maximum-transmission-unit) (MTU). My environment was some specific case. I was trying ssh from VMware Virtual Machine to Openstack Instance. [And openstack needed smaller packet](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/93#issuecomment-29942573) to be connected by [kitchen-openstack](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-openstack) which is [using](https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-openstack/blob/master/kitchen-openstack.gemspec) [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog), using NET::SSH. Not sure if this works for you, but have a try for these commands (assuming in Ubuntu):

1. check your MTU

   sudo netstat -i
2. You'll get some output like this, in the second column, you can check MTU:

   Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg

   eth0   1500 0      9658      0      0      0      308      0      0      0 BMRU

   lo    16436 0     12952      0      0      0    12952      0      0      0 LRU
3. For network interface eth0, you can try to reduce MTU from 1500 to, for example 1400 like this:

   sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1400
4. try net ssh

   ssh = Net::SSH.start("1.2.3.4", "user", password: "password", verbose: :debug)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give that a try and get back to you